# Django: want to sort comments by datetime

Tags: python, django, datetime

I have in my view comments and I want to sort them with the latest comment at the top of the list. However it is not working. I get this error.

`Caught TypeError while rendering: 'Comment' object is not iterable`

I am not so sure what is causing this problem. Here is my views and model which may help.

**Views**

```
def home(request):
    comments = Comment.objects.latest('datetime')
    return render_to_response('home.html', {'comments':comments}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**models**

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    note = models.TextField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `latest` method returns only one object, not an iterator:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#latest

Use the `order_by` method to order them by date (first example in the doc):
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by

Comment: I am assuming this is what I need. `comments = Comment.objects.order_by('-datetime')`

Answer (score 14):

The cleanest way is to add a class meta to your model and add the ordering parameter like this:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 40)
    datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    note = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-datetime']
       
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name)
```

So every query you make will be ordered by datetime.

Another advice do not choose "datetime" as a field name, datetime is a python module included in the standard lib.

Also see Django ordering docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#ordering).

Comment: You are missing comma `ordering = ('-datetime',)`

Answer (score 2):

Comment in `comments = Comment.objects.latest('datetime')` is NOT a collection of comment; it is a **single comment**.

What you want to do is create an array of Comment objects and iterate through that.